# Integration Test Issues for Kafka Consumer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

EDIT: The test now only passes when I use localhost:9092 for the bootstrap server, which is the default port I have my kafka/zookeeper docker image running on.

I need help with my integration test, which tests that the Kafka payload is consumed. I am using Test containers for the KafkaContainer and the MysqlContainer. The goal of the test is to ensure that the SUT can correctly consumer the payload from the Kafka produce, but the consumer is never being hit during the test. Despite not working correctly during the test, the code works as it should when I run it locally.

So far, I've tried using an EmbeddedKafkaBroker, which did not work, and I also tried changing the message topic. I know that the issue is somewhere in my configuration, but I can't exactly put my finger on it. Below, the application-test.properties, the SUT, the test class, and the logs will be attached in that specific order.

Also, the reason that I am using the `userRepository` for my assertions, is that whenever the payload is consumed, it is saved to the repository and I want to check if the saved user exists.

**application-test.properties**

```
# Kafka Properties
spring.kafka.topic.name=tappedtechnologies.emails.recipients

# Kafka Consumer Properties
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=userId
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.default.type=com.tappedtechnologies.userservice.events.RecipientSavedEvent
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
```

**SUT (RecipientPayloadConsumer)**

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RecipientPayloadConsumer implements KafkaConsumer<RecipientSavedEvent> {

    private final Creator<User> userCreator;

    @Override
    @KafkaListener(topics = "${spring.kafka.topic.name}", groupId = "${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}")
    public void consumePayload(@Payload RecipientSavedEvent payload) {
        log.info("Payload received from 'email-service': {}", payload);
        User userToSave = this.convertPayloadToUser(payload);
        try {
            userCreator.create(userToSave);
        } catch (IllegalStateException exception) {
            log.error("IllegalStateException caught attempting to save payload from email-service.");
            log.error("Message: {}", exception.getMessage());
            throw exception;
        }
    }

    private User convertPayloadToUser(RecipientSavedEvent payload) {
        return User.builder()
                .firstName(payload.getFirstName())
                .lastName(payload.getLastName())
                .email(payload.getEmail())
                .build();
    }
}
```

**RecipientPayloadConsumerTest**

```
@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
public class RecipientPayloadConsumerTests {

    private static KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private RecipientPayloadConsumer sut;

    @Container
    public static MySQLContainer<?> mySQLContainer = new MySQLContainer<>("mysql:latest");
    @Container
    public static KafkaContainer kafkaContainer = new KafkaContainer(DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.1"));

    @DynamicPropertySource
    public static void setProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.datasource.url", mySQLContainer::getJdbcUrl);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.username", mySQLContainer::getUsername);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.password", mySQLContainer::getPassword);
    }

    @BeforeAll
    public static void setUp() {
        Map<String, Object> producerProps = new HashMap<>();
        producerProps.put("bootstrap.servers", kafkaContainer.getBootstrapServers());
        producerProps.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        producerProps.put("value.serializer", "org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer");

        kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerProps));
        kafkaTemplate.setDefaultTopic("tappedtechnologies.emails.recipients");

        kafkaContainer.start();
        mySQLContainer.start();
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void afterEach() {
        userRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void tearDown() {
        kafkaContainer.stop();
        mySQLContainer.stop();
    }

    @Test
    public void consumePayload_Should_SavePayload() throws InterruptedException {
        RecipientSavedEvent expected = getPayload();
        kafkaTemplate.sendDefault(expected.getPayloadKey(), expected.toString());
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        User actual = userRepository.findByEmail(expected.getEmail()).orElse(null);

        assertThat(actual).isNotNull();
        assertThat(actual.getFirstName()).isEqualTo(expected.getFirstName());
        assertThat(actual.getLastName()).isEqualTo(expected.getLastName());
        assertThat(actual.getEmail()).isEqualTo(expected.getEmail());
    }

    private RecipientSavedEvent getPayload() {
        return RecipientSavedEvent.builder()
                .payloadKey(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .firstName("Randy")
                .lastName("Marsh")
                .email("randy@tegridyfarms.com")
                .build();
    }
}
```

**logs**

```
2023-04-23T21:07:12.300-07:00  INFO [Tapped Technologies - User Service,,] 63697 --- [    Test worker] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Instantiated an idempotent producer.
2023-04-23T21:07:12.324-07:00  INFO [Tapped Technologies - User Service,,] 63697 --- [    Test worker] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 3.3.2
2023-04-23T21:07:12.324-07:00  INFO [Tapped Technologies - User Service,,] 63697 --- [    Test worker] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: b66af662e61082cb
2023-04-23T21:07:12.324-07:00  INFO [Tapped Technologies - User Service,,] 63697 --- [    Test worker] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1682309232324
2023-04-23T21:07:12.993-07:00  WARN [Tapped Technologies - User Service,,] 63697 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 1 : {tappedtechnologies.emails.recipients=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
2023-04-23T21:07:12.994-07:00  INFO [Tapped Technologies - User Service,,] 63697 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Cluster ID: Im2Ds_vjQq289WTPzltJlA
2023-04-23T21:07:13.018-07:00  INFO [Tapped Technologies - User Service,,] 63697 --- [ad | producer-1] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] ProducerId set to 0 with epoch 0
2023-04-23T21:07:13.150-07:00  WARN [Tapped Technologies - User Service,,] 63697 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 4 : {tappedtechnologies.emails.recipients=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
2023-04-23T21:07:13.289-07:00  WARN [Tapped Technologies - User Service,,] 63697 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 5 : {tappedtechnologies.emails.recipients=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
2023-04-23T21:07:13.424-07:00  WARN [Tapped Technologies - User Service,,] 63697 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 6 : {tappedtechnologies.emails.recipients=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
2023-04-23T21:07:13.550-07:00  WARN [Tapped Technologies - User Service,,] 63697 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 7 : {tappedtechnologies.emails.recipients=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
2023-04-23T21:07:13.667-07:00  WARN [Tapped Technologies - User Service,,] 63697 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 8 : {tappedtechnologies.emails.recipients=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
2023-04-23T21:07:13.789-07:00  WARN [Tapped Technologies - User Service,,] 63697 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 9 : {tappedtechnologies.emails.recipients=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
2023-04-23T21:07:13.911-07:00  WARN [Tapped Technologies - User Service,,] 63697 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 10 : {tappedtechnologies.emails.recipients=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
2023-04-23T21:07:14.609-07:00  WARN [Tapped Technologies - User Service,,] 63697 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 11 : {tappedtechnologies.emails.recipients=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
2023-04-23T21:07:14.754-07:00  WARN [Tapped Technologies - User Service,,] 63697 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 12 : {tappedtechnologies.emails.recipients=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
2023-04-23T21:07:14.934-07:00  INFO [Tapped Technologies - User Service,,] 63697 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition tappedtechnologies.emails.recipients-0 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to mmZzWI7DSkGiNcBk1J0Lmw
```

Comment: Why areyou creating your own `KafkaTemplate` and there appears to be no mapping in your `@DynamicPropertySource` method for the kafka container. Which feels like they are disconnected from each other. Your container setup is weird as well `@TestContainers` will already manage the lifecycle of the `@Container`s so no need to do that yourself (as well). Finally I would suggest using something like Awaitility to write your tests instead of a hard thread.sleep. Also finally calling `toString` doesn't produce JSON, so I doubnt your listener will be able to deserialize your payload.

Comment: @M.Deinum — Thanks for input. A few things such as my container setup, and also calling toString must have completely flown over my head. I could use ObjectMapper to properly convert the payload to json. I’ll make those adjustments and respond again. Thank you!

Comment: Just inject the `KafkaTemplate` from the context, just remove that setup and juist place `@Autowired` on the `KafkaTemplate`. Spring Boot will inject one.

Comment: @M.Deinum -- Your tips helped me solve the error. I used ```@Autowired``` to inject the ```KafkaTemplate```, I removed the ```@BeforeAll``` setup and used the ```DynamicPropertyRegistry``` to add the kafka container bootstrap server to the registry. I also added the producer serializer in my ````application-test.properties```. I'll update the question with the adjusted code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of @M.Deinum, I solved the issue I was facing. It was quite simple; I used `@Autowired` to inject the `KafkaTemplate` from the context and removed the entire `@BeforeAll` setup. By removing the `@BeforeAll` setup, I had to use the `DynamicPropertyRegistry` and the `KafkaContainer` to add the `spring.kafka.bootstrap-server` to the properties.

Below is the adjusted code.

**application-test.properties**

```
# Kafka Properties
spring.kafka.topic.name=tappedtechnologies.test.topics

# Kafka Consumer Properties
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=testId
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.type.mapping=event:com.tappedtechnologies.userservice.events.RecipientSavedEvent
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.default.type=com.tappedtechnologies.userservice.events.RecipientSavedEvent
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer

# Kafka Producer Properties
# -- NEWLY ADDED -- #
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
```

**RecipientPayloadConsumerTests**

```
@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
public class RecipientPayloadConsumerTests {

    private static final String TOPIC = "tappedtechnologies.test.topics";

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, RecipientSavedEvent> kafkaTemplate;

    @Container
    public static MySQLContainer<?> mySQLContainer = new MySQLContainer<>("mysql:latest");
    @Container
    public static KafkaContainer kafkaContainer = new KafkaContainer(DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.1"));

    @DynamicPropertySource
    public static void setProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.datasource.url", mySQLContainer::getJdbcUrl);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.username", mySQLContainer::getUsername);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.password", mySQLContainer::getPassword);

        registry.add("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers", kafkaContainer::getBootstrapServers);
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void afterEach() {
        userRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    public void consumePayload_Should_SavePayload() throws InterruptedException {
        RecipientSavedEvent expected = getPayload();
        kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC, 0, Instant.now().getEpochSecond(), expected.getPayloadKey(), expected);
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        User actual = userRepository.findByEmail(expected.getEmail()).orElse(null);

        assert actual != null;
        assertThat(actual.getFirstName()).isEqualTo(expected.getFirstName());
        assertThat(actual.getLastName()).isEqualTo(expected.getLastName());
        assertThat(actual.getEmail()).isEqualTo(expected.getEmail());
    }

    private RecipientSavedEvent getPayload() {
        return RecipientSavedEvent.builder()
                .payloadKey(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .firstName("Randy")
                .lastName("Marsh")
                .email("randy@tegridyfarms.com")
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `@TestPropertySource` you can add `@ActiveProfile("test")` and Spring Boot will auto matically load that properties file.

Comment: Adding the `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers` dynamically is how magic is done!!! Thank you!